# compiling c++ program using gcc

Tags: c++, g++

```
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;
int 
main()
{
char name[30];
int marks;
ofstream fout("student.out");

cout<<"Enter name";
cin>>name;
cout<<"Enter marks secured:";
cin>>marks;

fout<<name<<endl;
fout<<marks<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

please help me compile the above program using gcc .
When i compile this program i get the following errors.

```
stdfile.cpp: In function 'int main()':
stdfile.cpp:12:1: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
stdfile.cpp:13:1: error: 'cin' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: why are you using `gcc` and not `g++`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::cin` and `std::cout` are in `<iostream>`. Please include that, and compile your C++ code with `g++`, not `gcc` - otherwise you'll get all sorts of linking issues.

Answer (score 4):

You need to

```
#include <iostream>
```

as well.

Also, compile the file with `g++` instead of `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compile with gcc, you should use printf instead of cout, scanf instead of cin and fprintf instead of fout.

Comment: gcc can quite happily compile C++ code, it just needs to be correct C++ code and it will need more explicit instructions with linking it

Answer (score 0):

> cout, cin etc. take part from  library. You must include it to get the program work